# Purchase in point of sale odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

I want to use Point of Sale odoo 14 community version. I want to know how i can handle purchase using POS so, qty to be sale update auto?

In product what is purpose of Can be Purchased. How i can made purchase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In point of sale module there is a field inventory_quantity (On Hand Quantity).
I want to know how to update this fields when balance goes to 0 (zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will give second question's answer.

**Can be sold**: If it is checked, you will be able to select the product in the Sales Order Lines

**Can be purchased**: If it is checked, you will be able to select the product in the Purchase Order Lines

So you want to handle your purchases in POS so my answer is ***NO, YOU CAN NOT*** without doing customization or by using third party module [example](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/pos_create_po_and_expense/)

Comment: Thank you, Noted. I have beginner level knowledge but i will try to customize and link to Purchase module with Point of Sale.

Comment: For this i have installed Purchase module and create Purchase Order. Its update  inventory_quantity (On Hand Quantity) field. So, my required feature already available, no need to customise.